# AES Decryption with key derivation function

Tags: elixir

I am working on porting a decryption function from .NET to elixir as a proof of concept.

Can anyone give me some guidance on if this is doable with the Erlang crypto module?  I have played around the `block_decrypt` functions but am never able to get the correct result. I am thinking my problem is coming from an incorrect key and IV.

I am unsure how to derive byte data from the encrypted plain text value to pass into `block_decrypt`.

Here is the elixir code I'm using to attempt to decrypt:

```
defmodule TestApp.Decrypt do
  @iv <<30,64,180,159,172,197,92,10,197,3,39,75,53,92,93,37>>

  def unpad(data) do
    to_remove = :binary.last(data)
    :binary.part(data, 0, byte_size(data) - to_remove)
  end


  def decrypt(data, key) do
    IO.puts "WOrking to decrypt #{data} using #{key}"
    padded = :crypto.block_decrypt(:aes_cbc256, key, @iv, :base64.decode(data))
    unpad(padded)
  end
end
```

I have a 32 byte key I'm trying to pass in but am getting this error:

```
Erlang error: :notsup
```

The Crypto Library points that error to the fact that dirty scheduler wasn't enabled on my erlang build, but I don't know if I'm going about this in the right direction before I look into that.

Comment: It would be better if you post the code used to encrypt, sample unencrypted and encrypted text (hexdump), and the code you wrote to decrypt which didn't work. I successfully implemented decryption functions for a client where the data was being encrypted by some crypto module in Perl, so as long as your algorithm is implemented by Erlang's `crypto`, it should be possible.

Comment: @Dogbert, thanks for the input. Ill put something together and update my question.

Comment: @Dogbert Edited Question.

Comment: In the crypto docs it says `May throw exception notsup in case the chosen Type is not supported by the underlying OpenSSL implementation.`

Comment: fwiw, I can run it without an exception if I remove `unpad`: http://s.ryanwinchester.ca/2W2n0L0H062v

Comment: @Botonomous can you post a sample value of `data` and `key` we can use to test?

Comment: There is an unresolved bug in `:crypto` reported here https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/5453 which seems to occur when you are using a debugger or observer.

Comment: data = r2NSggT78u0f2oARDO5U7XxdwAnEeJZuMvuyLOyo9q0=      KEY = config

Comment: @Botonomous did you mean to type another value for the key? `"config"` is not 32 bytes long.

Comment: @Dogbert, that is the key with .NET. I assume it is being padded but I know the key ends up being 32 bytes.

Comment: @Botonomous Erlang will not automatically pad the key. You'll need to pass a 32 byte key yourself as far as I know. I believe that's why you're getting `notsup` error. If I pass a 32 byte key, your code works.

Comment: @Dogbert can you give be an example key you used to get the code working?

Comment: @Botonomous I don't remember it now but I think this should work: `<<0::256>>`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks i figured out the issue. It is working now. I appreciate your help. My problem was the IO.PUTS was causing an issue outputting binary data to the console after the 32 byte key was passed in.

Answer (score 0):

The erlang crypto errors are not very helpful. It looks like you might have the wrong cipher specified. Instead of `aes_cbc256` you probably want `aes_256_cbc`. See http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#block_decrypt-4

You may also like to check-out a project I'm working on called Apoc which encapsulates this stuff into a more "Elixir like" API: https://github.com/coderdan/apoc

It supports AES in GCM mode so far but I would love to have some contributions for other ciphers!